# IIS cannot display static content even with AppPool with my Identity

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have a website running on IIS with its own Identity with a Custom credential which is my computer account (that is administrator). When I try to load the page, the Asp.Net MVC application execute but not the Javascript, neither CSS files. I have 401.3 error. I have enabled the IIS request log and this is what I see.

The application pool is my custom one. The authentification is anonymous. The user from token is NT Authority\IUSR ... this is what I do not understand... how come it's not my credential?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to active the Static File Handler of IIS and I had to set in the basic setting a credential that has the read right of the folder instead of the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set both my Application Pool Identity as the custom user account, and then also set the `Connect as...` settings as shown here:

https://serverfault.com/a/1063414/402955

[image: IIS Connect as Settings]